# Android vertical recyclerview with horizontal overflow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a document tree using a RecyclerView. Because the tree is expandable, I'm using a custom adapter for it. All of the layout items in the RecyclerView are set to WRAP_CONTENT width, along with the RecyclerView itself. Because the labels in the items can be long and nested, I want the list to be horizontally scrollable to see the clipped items, and the list orientation to be vertical. Comment if you need anything else.

### branch.xml

```xml
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <TextView
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

### activity

```xml
    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context=".TreeActivity">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

### Binding the view(The adapter is separately managed)

```kotlin
    class BranchViewHolder(val branchBinding: BranchBinding) : TreeViewBinder.ViewHolder(branchBinding.root)

    override fun getLayoutId(): Int = R.layout.branch
    override fun provideViewHolder(itemView: View?): BranchViewHolder = BranchViewHolder(BranchBinding.bind(itemView!!))

    override fun bindView(p0: BranchViewHolder?, p1: Int, p2: TreeNode<*>?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "bindView: ${p2?.isExpand}")
        val rotateDegree = if (p2?.isExpand == true) -90 else 0
        p0?.branchBinding?.arrow?.rotation = rotateDegree.toFloat()

        with(p2?.content as Branch) {
            p0?.branchBinding?.title?.text = this.name

            p0?.itemView?.layoutParams= RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        }
    }
```

### Screenshot

[image: Image#1]

**Problem - Want to horizontally scroll**

[image: Problem - Want to horizontally scroll]

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` to your `RecyclerView`.

For example if you want to scroll the items horizontally, try this one :

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

Don't forget to add the `orientation` for the vertical / horizontal scroll.

Comment: This will force the contents horizontally, I don't want that. See the image, contents are added vertically. but I need them to be scrollable in both directions.